# Precompiled in asp.net application not required

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a website project and some other projects that are tied up via a solution file. When I build the solution using visual studio, it does not create precompiled version of website but using msbuild to build the solution creates precompiled version.
We don't use precompiled code to deploy on servers so this version is not required in our process.
And this takes a lot of time to get created.

So how can I avoid creation of pre compiled version? Is there any switch or task that I can use in msbuild scripts to build the solution.
I need msbuild to simply build the solution.

currently the command that I am using is:

msbuild "ABC.sln"

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild on the command line features a /t switch, which allows you to define build targets. You would use this switch to target all the other subfolders in the solution, leaving the website untouched.

[MSBuild Command Line arguments on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Comment: But I need to build website also to check build errors just like Build web site in Visual Studio. That builds the website but does not create precompiled version.

Comment: Any one please can answer? when I am building my website via msbuild..it is automatically precompiling it... I do not want precompilation. How can I avoid it?